# Parse parts of sentence while preserving context in Python with regex

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a number of courses in json, and for each course there exists a prerequisite field that contains a list of the prerequisites for that particular course like this:

(for simplicity let's just follow AAAA111 format)

```
AAAA111, BBB111, CCC101, DDD104
```

Each course follows the format `\w{3,4}\d{3}`, so getting each one of this using regex in python wasn't too difficult.

Problem:

I don't know who the genius that thought this was the brilliant way to do it was, but there is *no consistent format whatsoever in how the list of prerequisites are listed*.  So here are some sample format of lists I've found:

```
AAAA111, BBB111, CCC101, and DDD104
AAAA111, BBB111, CCC101 or DDD104
AAAA111, AAAA112 or AAAA113, BBB333
AAA111 or BBB111, AND CCC111
AAA111 or BBB111 or CCC111 or DDD111
AAA111 or 112 or 222 or 333
AAA111 or instructor permission
AAA111/221
and so on... :(
```

There are thousands of courses, and I have found so many different formats like this that sometimes I wonder if it's just better to go through everything by hand whenever the weirdos exist.

So extracting the specific courses that are mentioned using regex to parse for matches to `\w{3,4}\d{3}` isn't hard.  Using regex to match for presence of key words like `or`, `and`, or `instructor permission` isn't hard either.

Where I'm stuck is preserving the context.

In above example:

```
AAAA111, BBB111, CCC101, and DDD104
```

Such prerequisite list means this course requires all 4 to be taken.

```
AAAA111, BBB111, CCC101 or DDD104
AAA111 or 112 or 222 or 333
```

Such prerequisite list means this course requiress only 1 or more of the 4 to be taken.

```
AAAA111, AAAA112 or AAAA113, BBB333
```

But for weirdos like this...

What can I do?  Obviously, just having a flag that gets activated when `or` or `and` or other such keywords present isn't going to work.  I'm stuck on how to best parse this while maintaining the context. A human reading this could easily figure out what the context is, but...

EDIT: Since clarity seems to be an issue, I'll try to be clearer here. 
What I would like to do is change each prerequisite courses list per course for all courses such that they all have 1 consistent, programmatically readable format.

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is.  Are you asking how to extract the course numbers, or how to represent which combinations of courses are acceptable?  For the latter, you will need more than regex.

Comment: Gah, sorry that it wasn't clear. I am trying to represent the combination of prerequisite courses in a clear way, and to do that I need to extract that information somehow from that mess. So from those examples, how to interpret the information and parse the lists that have no consistent format programmatically so I can put everything else into a new, consistent format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) which is great library for working with grammars.

If the entries have consistent (boolean) logic and you know how to interpret the comma between `and`'s and `or`'s than you could try parsing the entries using a script based on the [`simpleBool.py`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/detail/simpleBool.py) example from pyparsing:

```
import pprint
import string

from pyparsing import Word, nums, Literal, opAssoc, operatorPrecedence


course_name = Word(string.ascii_uppercase + nums + "/") | Literal("instructor permission")
comma_separator = Literal(',')
comma_separator.setParseAction(lambda t:"&&")

and_separator = Literal(', and') | Literal(', AND') | Literal('and')  | Literal('AND')
and_separator.setParseAction(lambda t:"&&")

or_separator = Literal('or') | Literal("OR")
or_separator.setParseAction(lambda t:"||")

course_line = operatorPrecedence(course_name,
                            [
                                (and_separator, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
                                (or_separator, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                                (comma_separator, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,),
                            ])

data = """AAAA111, BBB111, CCC101, and DDD104
AAAA111, BBB111, CCC101 or DDD104
AAAA111, AAAA112 or AAAA113, BBB333
AAA111 or BBB111, AND CCC111
AAA111 or BBB111 or CCC111 or DDD111
AAA111 or 112 or 222 or 333
AAA111 or instructor permission
AAA111/221
"""

for line in data.splitlines():
    results = course_line.parseString(line)
    print(line)
    pprint.pprint(results.asList()[0])
    print()
```

That prints:

```
AAAA111, BBB111, CCC101, and DDD104
['AAAA111', '&&', 'BBB111', '&&', ['CCC101', '&&', 'DDD104']]

AAAA111, BBB111, CCC101 or DDD104
['AAAA111', '&&', 'BBB111', '&&', ['CCC101', '||', 'DDD104']]

AAAA111, AAAA112 or AAAA113, BBB333
['AAAA111', '&&', ['AAAA112', '||', 'AAAA113'], '&&', 'BBB333']

AAA111 or BBB111, AND CCC111
['AAA111', '||', ['BBB111', '&&', 'CCC111']]

AAA111 or BBB111 or CCC111 or DDD111
['AAA111', '||', 'BBB111', '||', 'CCC111', '||', 'DDD111']

AAA111 or 112 or 222 or 333
['AAA111', '||', '112', '||', '222', '||', '333']

AAA111 or instructor permission
['AAA111', '||', 'instructor permission']

AAA111/221
'AAA111/221'
```

Comment: If comma is a synonym for AND, then they should be at equal levels in the precedence of operations. Change the first level definition in `operatorPrecedence` (which has been renamed to `infixNotation`, but they are the same) to: `(and_separator|comma_separator, 2, opAssoc.LEFT,)`.

Comment: Question -- I just noticed this (sorry it took awhile) -- in the second example `AAAA111, BBB111, CCC101 or DDD104`, the result returned by pyparsing is wrong there.  How would I fix that?  Not sure what the best way to do that is without screwing up everything else